# How to remove duplicates objects from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

In my code i have created one array called array1. In this array i have listed multiple objects. I want to filter out array1 objects values as unique and need to group ids with their respective values. I have added my code here,

**Array1**

```
var array1 = [
            {
                value:"A",
                id:1
            },
            {
                value:"B",
                id:1
            },
            {
                value:"C",
                id:2
            },
            {
                value:"B",
                id:5
            },
            {
                value:"A",
                id:2
            },
            {
                value:"A",
                id:1
            }
        ];
```

the result which i want,

```
[
            {
                group:"A",
                groupIds:[1, 2]
            },
            {
                group:"B",
                groupIds:[1, 5]
            },
            {
                group:"C",
                groupIds:[2]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Have you searched SO? There's some similar questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919074/js-group-array-values-by-groups, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873228/javascript-group-by-array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects

Comment: I searched and tried too. But the result which i added in my question is not coming like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach()` to group objects by values and `Set()` to remove duplicate ids from `groupIds`

```js
var array1 = [{"value":"A","id":1},{"value":"B","id":1},{"value":"C","id":2},{"value":"B","id":5},{"value":"A","id":2},{"value":"A","id":1}]

var result = [];
array1.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.value]) (this[e.value] = {group: e.value, groupIds: []}) && result.push(this[e.value])
  this[e.value].groupIds = [...new Set(this[e.value].groupIds.concat(e.id))]
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

In plain Javascript, you could use a hash table and [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for unique values.

```js
var array = [{ value: "A", id: 1 }, { value: "B", id: 1 }, { value: "C", id: 2 }, { value: "B", id: 5 }, { value: "A", id: 2 }, { value: "A", id: 1 }],
    grouped = array.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.value]) {
                hash[a.value] = { group: a.value, groupIds: [] };
                r.push(hash[a.value]);
            }
            if (hash[a.value].groupIds.indexOf(a.id) === -1) {
                hash[a.value].groupIds.push(a.id);
            }
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
_.uniqBy(objects, function (object) {
  return object.id;
});
```

that will do :)

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash:

```
_(array1)
  .uniqWith(_.isEqual)
  .groupBy('value')
  .map((v, k) => ({ group: k, groupIds: _.map(v, 'id')}))
  .value()
```

- [uniqWith()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#uniqWith) uses [isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#isEqual) to remove duplicates. You want to use this approach so that the `id` and the `value` props are compared.
- [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#groupBy) creates an object whose keys are the `value` property. Since there are three unique values in the initial array, this object should have three keys.
- [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#map) turns the object back into an array, with the expected `group` and `groupIds` properties.

Answer (score 0):

use `_.groupBy` and `_.mapValues` to iterate object values

```
var res = _.chain(array1)
    .groupBy('value')
    .mapValues(function(val, key) {
        return {
            group: key,
            groupIds: _.chain(val).map('id').uniq().value()
        };
    })
    .values()
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another in plain Javascript.

```
var hash = {}
array1.forEach( function(e) { 
    hash[e.value] = hash[e.value] || []; 
    if (hash[e.value].indexOf(e.id) == -1) { hash[e.value].push(e.id) }
})
var result = Object.keys(hash).map( function(key) { 
    return { group: key, groupIds: hash[key] } 
})
```